# How to capture file selection from a file dialog box using javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, filedialog

I have used the below code to create a file dialog box using java script

```
var input = $(document.createElement('input'));
input.attr("type", "file");
input.trigger('click');
```

File Dialog box appears correctly using the above code.

How do I capture the file name and other details if a file is selected using the Open button on the File Dialogue box?

Using the file which has been selected I would like to upload the selected file onto a server using an ajax request

I have tried a few options like below to capture click of the Open button. But it does not help. Any suggestions?

```
input.onchange = function(e) {
alert("File Selected"); 
};  

input.onclick = function(e) {
alert("File Selected");
};
```

Comment: use some opensource  file uploader plugins.
https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Basic-plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`file` inputs have a special property named `files`. You may access them (as an array, in case you have specified the `multiple` attribute) as follows:

```
var files = input.files;
```

The [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList) states:

> An object of this type is returned by the files property of the HTML
>   `<input>` element; this lets you access the list of files selected with
>   the `<input type="file">` element. It's also used for a list of files
>   dropped into web content when using the drag and drop API; see the
>   [`DataTransfer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DragDrop/DataTransfer) object for details on this usage.